# Voltage wrong reading for ph_ph

Tags: voltage, transformer

I measured ph-ph voltage (l1-l2) equals 100 v, (l1-l3) & (l2-l3) equals 55 v. However, when I measured ph_n equals 55 v for the 3 phases. I tried to measure earthing but all neutral points all well earthed.

Comment: Welcome to EE. The voltage is labeled as V or U, current is labeled as I, resistance R,...If you are measuring voltage then V1-V2 = 100V, ...You didn't mention what  is the nominal three phase voltage in your country.

Comment: What exactly are you reading voltage on and with for that matter?